# Looking for a good pixel art tool (mobile, browser)

Tags: mobile, pixel

I’m looking for a good pixel art tool that can be used on mobile in browser, something around the same style as [Piskel](https://piskelapp.com/), any suggestions?

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Pixilart](https://www.pixilart.com/draw). It is a good tool, and it is very responsive so you can definitely use it on a mobile browser.

Comment: I’ve used that, it’s not very good on mobile (and don’t even get me started on the app, not being able to set a custom canvas size is pretty annoying)

Comment: @LabboLab Actually you can set a custom canvas size on mobile, via settings > new > blank canvas.